# Why working PWA on Android Chrome and Firefox becomes white screen on iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, angular, safari, progressive-web-apps

I've tried Angular 7 and 8, even Ionic on iOS devices of version 11/12.4. All the same result: This PWA web app works fine on android Chrome and Firefox, but I only get white screen when I add this web page on home screen.

Here is my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "caiex-angular6",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json",
    "build": "ng build --base-href ./",
    "buildTest": "ng build  --prod --build-optimizer --configuration=test",
    "buildProd": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer --configuration=production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "echarts": "^4.1.0",
    "element-angular": "^0.7.6",
    "jsrsasign": "^8.0.12",
    "ngx-echarts": "^4.1.0",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

and this is the **index.html** I got by using `ng add @angular/pwa`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
  <title>My PWA</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/iconfont.css">
  <script>
    document.documentElement.style.fontSize = document.documentElement.clientWidth / 7.5 + "px";
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

I can debug this on Mac Chrome and Safari, but no luck on iOS Safari, because it does not support PWA debugging well yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the package.json, `"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"` is the reason why Safari got a white screen. Remove this if you did not use any babel syntax in your Angular projects will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

iOS has till a lot of open parts about PWAs support. Do you get any console errors? Is web app manifest correctly seen via the browser?

Which version of Safari are you using?
On [can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=service%20worker) web site you can verify the Safari version that supports service workers.